# /bin/sh: Applications: command not found

Tags: python, cron

I want to run a script from crontab. This is the command:

```
* * * * * * /opt/anaconda3/bin/python3 /Users/Usr/Documents/script.py
```

When it tries to run, I get an alert that I have mail in the terminal and it says-

```
Message
/bin/sh: Applications: command not found
```

I'm confused because the command isn't a .sh file, its just a python script

I tried chmod +e and I added a shebang to the top of my python script

Comment: Try 6 `*` instead of 7. More info to it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46369649/3565291

Comment: Nope, I reduced to six asterisks and same error

Comment: The documentation here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46369649/3565291) actually mentions 5. Do you get the same with 5 *?

Comment: Yes I get the same result with 5 *

Comment: Do you get the same result after calling `* * * * * echo 'leon trozky' >> /Users/<your-name>/Desktop/foo.txt 2>&1`? (Creating the `foo.txt` beforehand)?

Comment: Can you share your script.py so one can try to reproduce locally?